# Algorithms for hashing a list of values, and later checking whether a value is in that list

Tags: java, algorithm, web-services

I am working on a set of services, and a client JAR file which is intended to be the sole means of calling these services.  The client JAR will be used by multiple applications (all internal).  However, we would like some services to be allowed for some client applications and not others.

I'm playing around with different approaches for meeting this goal, but one approach is to give each application a "context" value to pass at run-time.  This value would represent the list of services allowed to that client application, and a service would be able to quickly calculate whether or not it is on that list.

Each service would have its own ID value, probably hard-coded into the Java class as a `static final` variable.  For each client application, I would put together a list of allowed services, probably using a Groovy script or very basic web app.  A bit of Reflection-based code would collect all of those ID values, and generate a hash representing them all.

I would give this "context" hash to client application owners along with the client JAR, and they would pass it back at run-time when calling a service.  The service would use the same (or a related) hashing algorithm, to quickly check whether or not its ID is contained within the hash.  If so, the service proceeds.  If not, it throws an exception.  This approach obviously would not protect against *deliberate* abuse, but these are all internal services and we only need to block negligent misuse.

I'm not sure which hashing algorithm to use (or if "hashing" is even the right word for it).  I could just collect all of the allowed ID's as a `String`, and later check to see whether a given ID is contained within that string.  However, the "context" value would then be huge and unwieldy.  I'm sure that there are standard mathematical approaches for hashing a list of values, and later checking whether a given raw value is in that list.  Probably some that are already neatly packaged and exposed in the Java world.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: When you say "hash," do you mean that false positives or false negatives are okay?  Or do you just want a way to losslessly combine all the IDs together?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to combine or store anything.  I just need to know that when I later take a given ID value and compare it to a given hash, I can tell whether that value was factored into the generation of that hash.  If an algorithm lets you reverse the process and extract the original values losslessly, then that's fine... but I only need a one-way check.

Comment: To clarify- is it bad if you get back the wrong answer to "was this part of the set that generated this hash?" For example, is it bad to say "yes" to a service that was not included or "no" to a service that was included?

Comment: I'd be interested to know more detail behind why you're asking.  However, I suppose that I could live with the former more so the latter.  A small number of erroneous matches is okay, but I couldn't handle a value failing to match when it should have.

Comment: The main reason I was curious is because what you're describing seems like it might be a good fit for a Bloom Filter (assuming you have a bunch of services and not much space to store things), but this loses some precision.  I guess I'm not fully clear on the complete use case, so I don't want to offer advice that's completely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking at is passing a compressed flat file/XML to the service. The service will read the file contents (after decompressing) into a `HashSet` and check if its *id* is present in the `HashSet`.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing eventually.  I serialized a java.util.HashSet object, and passed it back and forth as a Base64-encoded string.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: The original thoughts I had in mind came from working with the "wxWidgets" GUI framework years ago.  I recalled configuration being based on combining multiple numeric values into one field, and having the capability to later determine whether a particular value went into making that.  However, after downloading the wxWidgets code and refreshing my knowledge, it turns out that these values were enums rather than numeric values... so it's an entirely different concept that doesn't fit what I'm doing here.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to implement permission and allow only those application who have the required permission.

For details, please read the detail topic on android permission :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: Hmm?  But this isn't an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). I think it’s even in [standard libraries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Answer (score 0):

What are the bounds on these IDs you're going to receive?

You should use a hash table, but if these IDs are within relatively small bounds (in relation to your system's memory), you can just create the easiest hash table there is.

If these IDs are within n and n+m, make an array of size m and set each element to FALSE. For each ID you want to add, set array[ID - n] to TRUE. To check if an ID has been passed in, just check if (array[ID - n])